# How can you tell if a Influx Database contains data?

Tags: influxdb

I'm currently trying to count the number of rows in an InfluxDB, but the following fails.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "TempData_Quarantine_1519835017000_1519835137000"..:MEASUREMENT";
```

with the message

```
InfluxData API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"error":"error parsing query: found :, expected ; at line 1, char 73"}
```

To my understanding this query should be checking all measurements and counting them?

(I inherited this code from someone else, so apologies for not understanding it better)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a binary answer to the question "tell if a Influx Database contains data?" then just do

```
select count(*) from /.*/
```

In case if the current retention policy in the current database is empty (contains 0 rows) it will return just nothing. Otherwise it will return something like this:

```
name: api_calls
time count_value
---- -----------
0    5

name: cpu
time count_value
---- -----------
0    1
```

Also you can specify retention policy explicitly:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "TempData_Quarantine_1519835017000_1519835137000"./.*/
```

Comment: "TempData_Quarantine_1519835017000_1519835137000" would be the name of a RP in this answer? It was the name of a db, I should have clarfied

Comment: Yes, it will. In your case then just don't forget to `use TempData_Quarantine_15198...` before executing a query.